# Phase transitions and unitarily equivalence of representations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, representation-theory, phase-transition

my doubt is the following. In the book "Symmetry breaking" by Strocchi, he says that if two irreducible representations of the same algebra are not unitarily equivalent, it means that, from a statistical mechanics point of view, there is a phase transition (e.g. solid to liquid). Viceversa, if all the representations are unitarily equivalent there is no phase transition. However, it has been proved by Dell'Antonio (Comm. Math. Phys. 9, 81, 1967) that two KMS states of Free Fermi gas with temperatures β1 and β2 give two equivalent representations ⟺ β1=β2. At the same time, however, no phase transition occurs for Free Fermi gases. How's it that possible? I suspect because the two KMS states are not pure states, but I feel I am missing something.